# Backbone: put collection title and collection items into one json file

Tags: json, backbone.js

I have a FAQ on my website.
The questions are in a json file, but I want some extra info (like the title of the faq) also in the json file. 
My json file looks like this:

```
{
    "titel": "FAQ title",
    "items": [
        {
            "question": "Question 1",
            "answer": "Answer 1"
        },
        {
            "question": "Question 2",
            "answer": "Answer 2"
        }
    ]
 }
```

Collection extend code:

```
Faq.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Faq.Model,
    url: '/scripts/json/faq.json',
    parse: function(response){
        return response.items;
    }
});
```

The items are parsed, because this is for the render loop.
But how can I show the title on the page?

This is the render function:

```
render: function() {
        this.el.innerHTML = this.template({
            titel: 'Helpdesk'
        });

        console.log(this);

        this.collection.each(function( faqitem ) {
            var faqItemView = new Faq.Views.ModelView({ model: faqitem });

            this.$el.find('.faq').append( faqItemView.render().el );
        }, this);

        return this;
    }
```

I want to put the title from the json file at the place where 'Helpdesk' is.

I hope I'm clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your parse function like this :

```
parse: function(response){
    this.title = response.title;
    return response.items;
}
```

and then in your render function :

```
this.el.innerHTML = this.template({
    titel: this.collection.title // pay attention to the titel not being title :)
});
```